Can an Python writeline() be used in an IF statement?
I'm trying to make a simple password manager. This is my function for adding passwords:
]
def add():
    
    cont=input("You would like to add a password? (y/n)")
    if cont.capitalize() == "Y":
        passwords = open("Passwords.txt","a")
        username_ = input("What is the username?")
        password_ = input("What is the password?")
        L = [username_, " ", password_]
        if(passwords.writelines(L)):
            print("Written successfully!")
            print("Quiting to option select...\n")
            main()
        else:
            print("Hmm. That didn't seem to work.")
            main()
    else:
        print("Quiting to option select...\n")
        main()
    

I always receive "Hmm. That didn't seem to work." when I try to add new passwords. The intended functionality of this is so that if a password is written, then it will say written successfully. Written in this case means appended, hence the 'a' in the opening of the file.
I tried using sudo to run it, but that wasn't the issue. I tried changing the append, to just 'w'.

writeline doesn't return anything. You should use a try/except block instead

What do you think passwords.writelines(L) returns, and why do you think that?

Note, however, that it's quite unlikely that writelines will fail, once the open has succeeded.

You know that there's documentation that clearly explains the arguments and return values of all the standard functions?

You could use try-except method.
try:
    passwords.writelines(L)
except Exception as x:
    print("Hmm. That didn't seem to work")
    print(f"Returned error: {x}")
else:
    print("Written successfully!")
    print("Quitting to option select...\n")

Edited by adding Python identifier, fixed original author's typo and removed the bare except:

Please use block quoting when inserting code so that it gets formatted correctly.

Sorry I'll edit that and fix it!

Be aware that using bare except: is bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except

writeLines does not have any return value and therefore would have no value in using in a if statement :)
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/writelines.html
